# create array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create this from within a loop. I need to have multiple arrays within an array but without having a key?

```
'items' => array(
    array(
        'd' => 'description 1',
        'u' => 12,
        'q' => 1,
        'type' => 1001001,
        'vatRate' => 0.20,
    ),
    array(
        'd' => 'description 2',
        'u' => 125,
        'q' => 1,
        'type' => 1001002,
        'vatRate' => 0.20,
    ),
),
```

This is my code so far....

```
$items = array();
$num = count($result);
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $key => $v) {
    $items .= array(
        'd' => $v['d'],
        's' => $v['s'],
        'q' => 1,
        'type' => $v['type'],
        'vatRate' => 0.20,
    );
    if ($i != $num) {
        $items .= ",";
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($items);
```

I'm just getting ArrayArrayArray though?

Answer (score 4):

change your code to this :

```
$items=array();
foreach ($result as $key => $v) {

    $items[0][] =array(
        'd' => $v['d'],
        's' => $v['s'],
        'q' => 1,
        'type' => $v['type'],
        'vatRate' => 0.20
        );
}
print_r($items);
```

Comment: this comes out as [0]=>array()[1]=>array() - is that the same as array(array(),array())?